# How to create, assign to, and print Unicode character

Tags: c, unicode, variable-assignment

Can anyone explain to me how to create a variable (in c), assign a Unicode character to that variable, and then print that variable. I am probably missing something here,but I can't work it out. Also, is there any way I can include variables in a variable name?

`int ttt x;
x=1;
tttx==ttt1;`

I know that that code is terrible, but what should I do, as this does not seem to be the way to go about it?

Comment: Off topic you need to ask on StackOverflow. But a few things you need to clear up: Unicode is a concept. It is implemented in languages as an encoded format: UTF-8/UTF-16/UTF-32 (and a couple of other wierd ones). What do you mean by print (do you mean draw the associated code points glyph in a window. How do I print the encoded UTF character to a stream etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the second question first: No, there is no way you can include variables in the name of another variable. If you need a flexible mapping from names to values, a *hash map* would work well. If you can switch to C++, you can use `std::unordered_map<>` for that. If you need to stick to C, you should find a library that implements hash maps and link with that. It's easy to find numerous examples on [Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=hash+map+implementation+c&fp=e96d075593eb5f5f), and there also several SO (Stackoverflow) questions related to that.

As for the main question: If you know the Unicode code point of the character you want to print, best assign that to an `int32_t` and then convert it to the desired encoding.

There are various encodings for Unicode, the most widely used is UTF-8. If that is what you want, the conversion from a plain `int32_t` to a UTF-8 `char` sequence is the same as a conversion frm UCS-4 to UTF-8. There are plenty libraries available that provide functions for this conversion. For a quick overview, see [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#libs).